# Issue with global variables

Tags: android, global-variables

I defined some global variables in my app by extending Application, as shown below. When I leave the app, open more apps and play a bit with them, and go back to my app, the global variables have been deleted and my app crashes. I've got 2 questions:

1- How can this be possible?

2- How can I force my app to exit when going to background? I know I'm not supposed to do it, but I can't find other solution...

Thanks

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application { 

    public static HashMap<Integer, String> ID2Cat = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    // User logged bool
    public static boolean isLogged = false;

    // Current menu item
    public static int currentMenuItem = 0;
    public static boolean isHome = false;

    // Goodideas    
    public static JSONObject goodIdeas = new JSONObject();

    // Meteo
    public static JSONArray weatherItems = new JSONArray();

    // More stuff

}
```

**Logcat**

Here's what makes me think my app is killed. This is shown at some point while playing with other apps.

```
I/ActivityManager( 2465): Process com.mysite.myapp (pid 23538) has died.
I/WindowManager( 2465): WIN DEATH: Window{4852a678 com.mysite.myapp/com.mysite.myapp.Home paused=false}
I/WindowManager( 2465): WIN DEATH: Window{485b63a8 com.mysite.myapp/com.mysite.myapp.Home paused=false}
I/WindowManager( 2465): WIN DEATH: Window{4826fbf8 com.mysite.myapp/com.mysite.myapp.ItemList paused=false}
I/WindowManager( 2465): WIN DEATH: Window{48286f90 com.mysite.myapp/com.mysite.myapp.ItemDetail paused=false}
W/GpsLocationProvider( 2465): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
D/GpsLocationProvider( 2465): stopNavigating
D/gps_BRCM( 2465): [status check] on_stop() : GPS_STATUS_SESSION_END
D/gps_BRCM( 2465): gps_engine_status_update 2
D/GpsLocationProvider( 2465): send an intent to notify that the GPS has been enabled or disabled
D/gps_BRCM( 2465): gps_stop: called
V/GpsLocationProvider( 2465): hybridGpsSensorDeregister : No registered sensorManager
D/GpsLocationProvider( 2465): hybridGpsSensorDeregister
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- How can this be possible?

Your process may be terminated at any point. You cannot assume how long any static data members or custom `Application` objects will live. They should only be used as a cache, at best.

> 2- How can I force my app to exit when going to background?

You don't.

> I know I'm not supposed to do it

Not only that, but it will not help you in this case. All it will do is mean that you crash 100% of the time, since you didn't actually bother to initialize properly.

> but I can't find other solution.

Initialize your data. If your application is crashing because a new custom `Application` instance was created, your `Application` subclass has bugs, which you need to fix.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize your data". When launching the app, a splash screen is shown during which all the global variables are initialized. There is no way to have data that are only deleted when the app is killed (ie when all activities are finished)?

Comment: @jul: "When launching the app, a splash screen is shown during which all the global variables are initialized." -- that is not a wise move. "There is no way to have data that are only deleted when the app is killed (ie when all activities are finished)? " -- that is what is happening already. However, "all activities are finished" when the OS decides, which can be whenever. If the user leaves your app, Android can finish the activities and terminate the process at any point.

Comment: Why is loading all my data in the splash screen (i.e. when the app in launched) not a wise move? I get them from web services and doing the http request + parsing the json afterwards would make the app less responsive. Moreover, when I open my app when it's been in background (using another app for instance), it should either start again and load my init data, or start from where I leave it if the activity has not been killed. In the former case, if the activity is still alive, my global variables should not have been deleted, right?

Comment: @jul: "Why is loading all my data in the splash screen (i.e. when the app in launched) not a wise move?" -- because users want to use your app, not stare at a splash screen. Redesign your app to provide *some* *real* functionality while you are loading the data in the background. Along the way, you can arrange to trigger this data load even if your process was terminated. "it should either start again and load my init data, or start from where I leave it if the activity has not been killed" -- and your proof of this is... what, exactly?

Comment: I added the logcat that makes me think my app is killed. This is why I don't understand why it does not restart from scratch (i.e. from the splash screen where the data is loaded).

Comment: @jul: How do you "go back to my app" that is triggering the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Clicking on my app icon in the app menu.

Comment: @jul: In a normal "Android's shutting you down to free up RAM" scenario, you are correct, as clicking on the app's icon in the launcher should bring up the initial launcher activity (which in this case I presume is your splash screen). I do not know why you are getting the navigation behavior that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the appropriate life-cycle event handlers to save data and restore it upon re-activation: onSaveInstanceState(), onPause(), and onResume().  You cannot safely assume that your global fields will remain intact.

I would suggest familizarizing yourself with the  [Activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, you must initialize your declared variables in Application.OnCreate, I have just tested and it works, when the application crash it calls Application.OnCreate again.

I wish that helped.

Answer (score 0):

`@Override onPause` in your activity and  then use finish();

Answer (score 0):

The `Application` class is for initializing global variables - so you have this part correct. However, you will have to declare these variables in another class, since the `Application` only is called when the app launches anew - not when it is in the background.

You should also make these initializations in the `Application`'s `onCreate()` method (using the `@Override` annotation).

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar problem and basically this article explains it well http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/

This being the key paragraph and what is happening to you:

> Which brings us to the core of the problem: The application object will not stay in memory forever, it will get killed. Contrary to popular belief, the app won’t be restarted from scratch. Android will create a new Application object and start the activity where the user was before to give the illusion that the application was never killed in the first place.

I know this post is old but thought that this might be helpful for future users.